# 404 NOT FOUND Symfony after clearing cache

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Everything was working just fine and I was editing twigs but realized that changes doesn't reflect on my website.

So I tried `/bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

After that I got an `HTTP 500` and when I go to `web/app_dev.php/` I get this:

> ContextErrorException in ClassCollectionLoader.php line 241:
>   Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory

Any idea why ?

Comment: Sorry, but that is not much to go on. Do you have any entries in your log (`var/log/dev.log`) that show errors/exceptions? The notice seems weird, do you know where it comes from?

Answer (score 1):

You trying to use app_dev.php file, from symfony 4 you don't have app.php and app_dev.php files. To turn on the dev or prod environment you should set it on .env file.